# OneDrive links are showing blank page in iOS WebView

Tags: ios, sharepoint, xamarin.forms

I am loading a **SharePoint** site in **Xamarin Forms WebView**. The Sharepoint site internally has OneDrive links. When the links are clicked blank page is loaded.

When I click on any of the **OneDrive** files that open in a new tab are showing a blank page in the iOS mobile app. 
Here is the [link](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=58520) to the Bugzilla

Comment: are you added the transport security in your app

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Yes, I have added.

Comment: r u get any block report in your console

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik No, it just returns the URL as "about: blank"

Comment: no no i said - you get console report